# jquery get visibility of toggled div

Tags: jquery, toggle, visibility

I have a page with several buttons and an associated  text div. I can toggle the visibility of the text div by clicking each button. I would like to get the visibility of each text div and use it to re-produce the page state. How do I get the “visibility” of the text divs?

My code so far only responds with “visible”.

Many thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Visibility</title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getVis(textDiv){
            if ($(textDiv).is(":visible")) {
                alert("visible");
            }else{
                alert("not visible");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="$(div1).slideToggle(500), getVis(div1)">button 1</button>
    <div id = "div1">div 1 text</div>
    <br>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="$(div2).slideToggle(500), getVis(div2)">button 2</button>
    <div id = "div2">div 2 text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `slideToggle` being a transition (over time operation), check visibility *prior* to invoking the transition, i.e. reverse the call order. For example

```
 <button id="btn1" onclick="getVis(div1), $(div1).slideToggle(500)">button 1</button>
```

Here's a demo.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Visibility</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getVis(textDiv){       
            if ($(textDiv).is(":visible")) {
                alert("visible");
            }else{
                alert("not visible");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
  <body>
      <button id="btn1" onclick="getVis(div1), $(div1).slideToggle(500)">button 1</button>
      <div id = "div1">div 1 text</div>
      <br>
      <button id="btn2" onclick="getVis(div2), $(div2).slideToggle(500)">button 2</button>
      <div id = "div2">div 2 text</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To determine the visibility state *after* the transition, call `getVis` from the completion routine like so

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="$(div1).slideToggle(500, function() { getVis(div1) })">button 1</button>
```

Here's a demo of the completion approach.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Visibility</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getVis(textDiv){       
            if ($(textDiv).is(":visible")) {
                alert("visible");
            }else{
                alert("not visible");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="$(div1).slideToggle(500, function() { getVis(div1) })">button 1</button>    <div id = "div1">
     div 1 text
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="$(div2).slideToggle(500, function() { getVis(div2) })">button 2</button>
    <div id = "div2">div 2 text</div>
</body>
</html>
```